# Divide every row that shares an identifier in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

```
  id item val 
o a  tire  5
1 a  brick 5
2 b  wheel 9
3 b  brick 6
4 c  ice   6
5 c  brick 3
6 d  brick 3
7 d  grass 6
```

Let's say I have this dataframe. I want to divide the value of "brick" by the value of an item that shares an id with "brick". The end result should look like this:

```
  id item val per/brick
o a  tire  5     1
1 a  brick 5     1
2 b  wheel 9     0.7
3 b  brick 6     1
4 c  ice   6     .5
5 c  brick 3     1
6 d  brick 3     .5
7 d  grass 6     2
```

I tried declaring the column using a for loop:

```
perbrick=[]
for x in df['id']:
    if df[df['id']==x & df['item']!='brick']:
        perbrick.append(df[(df['id']==x)&(df['item']=='brick')]['val']/df[df['id']==x]['val']
    else:
        perbrick.append(1)
```

However this just yields `TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]`

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I want to actually divide brick's value by the other item's value

Comment: Your last row should be `7 d  grass 6  2`. What happens if you have more than one `brick` per `id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
bricks = (df['val']
          .where(df['item'].eq('brick'), 0)
          .groupby(df['id']).transform('sum')
          )

df['per/brick'] = df['val'].rdiv(bricks).round(1)
```

output:

```
  id   item  val  per/brick
o  a   tire    5        1.0
1  a  brick    5        1.0
2  b  wheel    9        0.7
3  b  brick    6        1.0
4  c    ice    6        0.5
5  c  brick    3        1.0
6  d  brick    3        1.0
7  d  grass    6        0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
#create a dictionary of id, val for brick items
d=dict(df.loc[df['item'].eq('brick')][['id','val']].values)
```

resulting dictionary

```
{'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 3, 'd': 3}
```

```
# divide by the brick mapped value
df['perbrick']=df['val'].div( df['id'].map(d)  )
df
```

```
    id  item    val     perbrick
o   a   tire    5   1.0
1   a   brick   5   1.0
2   b   wheel   9   1.5
3   b   brick   6   1.0
4   c   ice     6   2.0
5   c   brick   3   1.0
6   d   brick   3   1.0
7   d   grass   6   2.0
```

Comment: Why convert to dictionary and then map back to series when you can [directly use `groupby.transform`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74045933/16343464)? ;)

Comment: computationally groupby and transform is heavier than dict. In timeit test, it was 1.83 ms (mine) vs 2.33 ms (yours)  @mozway .  Besides, this is also a lighter solution, given the OP objective

Comment: I don't get such a difference with OP's example, however on a larger dataset (80K rows) the dict+map approach is ~ 4 times slower, >5 times slower on 800K rows